# get data from DB as range using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table_db like this

```
ID     DATA         PRICE
1      2014-01-01   10
2      2014-01-02   10
3      2014-01-03   10
4      2014-01-04   10
5      2014-01-01   20
6      2014-01-01   20
7      2014-01-01   30
8      2014-01-01   30
```

I'd like a sql query that give me this output

```
from 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-04 price is 10
from 2014-01-05 to 2014-01-06 price is 20
from 2014-01-08 to 2014-01-08 price is 30
```

how can i do?

Comment: 2014-01-08 ??? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,date DATE NOT NULL
 ,price INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1      ,'2014-01-01',   10),
 (2      ,'2014-01-02',   10),
 (3      ,'2014-01-03',   10),
 (4      ,'2014-01-04',   10),
 (5      ,'2014-01-05',   20),
 (6      ,'2014-01-06',   20),
 (7      ,'2014-01-07',   10),
 (8      ,'2014-01-08',   10);


        SELECT a.date start
             , MIN(c.date) end
             , a.price
          FROM my_table a
          LEFT 
          JOIN my_table b 
            ON b.price = a.price
           AND b.id = a.id - 1
          LEFT 
          JOIN my_table c 
            ON c.price = a.price
           AND c.id >= a.id 
          LEFT 
          JOIN my_table d 
            ON d.price = a.price
           AND d.id = c.id + 1
         WHERE b.id IS NULL 
           AND c.id IS NOT NULL
           AND d.id IS NULL
         GROUP 
            BY a.id;
 +------------+------------+-------+
 | start      | end        | price |
 +------------+------------+-------+
 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-04 |    10 |
 | 2014-01-05 | 2014-01-06 |    20 |
 | 2014-01-07 | 2014-01-08 |    10 |
 +------------+------------+-------+
```

Note that this particular solution assumes that ids are contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Sort table by date (ASC) and then do something like this:

```
$result; //array with DB result
for($i = 0; $i<count($result); $i++)
    if(isset($result[$i+1])
        echo 'From' . $result [$i] ['data'] . ' to '. $result [$i+1] ['data'] . ' price is ' . $result [$i] ['price'];
```

Comment: I tried
$sql="Select * from fatture ORDER BY data ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

for($i = 0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    if(isset($result[$i+1])
        {echo 'From'.$result[$i]['data']. ' to '.$result[$i+1]['data']. ' price is ' .$result[$i]['price'];}
}

but it doesn't work...

Comment: Thats becouse `mysql_query()` doesn't return an array. See PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and use `mysql_fetch_array`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Maybe see the nice big pink bit too.